# onDelete = NO_ACTION causes error: "SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" (code 787)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I am using Room on top of SQLite for Android, and I have the following two Pojo entities:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String eventId;
    private String eventName;
}
```

---

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"eventId","attendeeId"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = Event.class,
                        parentColumns = "eventId",
                        childColumns = "eventId" ,onDelete = NO_ACTION)
        })
public class Attendee {
    @NonNull
    private String eventId;
    @NonNull
    private String attendeeId;
}
```

When I try to delete a record from the Event table, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:732)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:45)
        at com.minapharm.hixspro.POJO.Room.Events.EventDao_Impl.deleteTable(EventDao_Impl.java:168)
```

However, if I change the onDelete to CASCADE, no problem occurs!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html#ondelete).

> By default, `NO_ACTION` is used.

You don't need to provide it explicitly.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"eventId","attendeeId"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = Event.class,
                        parentColumns = "eventId",
                        childColumns = "eventId")
        })
public class Attendee {
    @NonNull
    private String eventId;
    @NonNull
    private String attendeeId;
}
```

Also, You need to understand the Database is created once. You should reinstall the application and then check whether the delete works or Not.

**Edited:** As you have defined the ForeignKey but not onDelete CASCADE, You will have to remove all entries manually from Attendee which are pointing to the Event Table row- you are deleting.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. `@ForeignKey` annotation helps to ensure that an entry can't get into an invalid state (for instance, foreign key can't point to an entry that does not exist).

Imagine you have `Event(1, "some event")` in your database as well as an attendee `Attendee(1, 1)`. If the event is deleted, than the attendee entry will get into the invalid state, because it's foreign key `eventId` does not point to a valid entry. That's why you get an exception with description `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`.

`onDelete = CASCADE` ensures that all the dependent entries will be erased with the referenced entry itself: in the described earlier case `Attendee(1, 1)` will just also get erased from the database when the referenced event entry (`Event(1, "some event")`) gets deleted.